# Detect Beginning and Ending state of Scroll Wheel event in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, event-handling, scrollwheel

Cocoa provides many useful methods to detect the *beginning* and *ending* states of gestures and mouse clicks. For mouse clicks, we can easily override `mouseDown:` and `mouseUp:` methods. However, we don't seem to have a way to do the same for mouse scrolling event -- we are only provided with `scrollWheel:` method which is activated when scrolling happens.

I have tried `beginGestureWithEvent:` but it only responds to touch events.

Is there a way to detect the beginning and the ending states of mouse scrolling in Cocoa?

Comment: Do you use pure NSView or NSScrollView?

Comment: This is for generic NSView. I plan to use scrollView event for something non-related to manipulating the view, like changing certain member variables.

Answer (score 2):

As I see there's no such a simple solution.
But you still can do this.

The most evident is using timer to check when the wheel did scroll last time. I prefer using lightweight GCD-timers for this purposes (they also ARC-capable objects instead of NSTimer's which are storing `strong` target-references).

```
- (void) scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)event
{
  _lastStamp = mach_absolute_time(); // get current timestamp
  if (!_running)
  {
    if (!_timer)
      [self createTimerSource];
    if (!_running)
      dispatch_resume(_timer); 
    _running = YES;
  }
}

- (void)createTimerSource
{
  NSTimeInterval timeout = ...;
  _timer=dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, _timerQueue);
  dispatch_source_set_timer(_timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, timeout * NSEC_PER_SEC, 0);
  // set the event handler
  dispatch_source_set_event_handler(_timer, ^{
     uint64_t stamp = mach_absolute_time(); // current stamp
     if (stamp - _lastStamp > some_tolerance_value)
     {
       // wheel did end scroll
       if (_running)
         dispatch_source_cancel(_timer);
       _running = NO;
     }
  });
}
```

Check the article out to know more about [Dispatch Sources](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html).

Comment: Thank you for the approach. I can see now that it's possible to do but not sure if this is the best answer. I upvote your answer for appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I've found to detect onScrollWheelDown and onScrollWheelUp is to use `event.phase == MayBegin` for onDown `event.phase == Cancelled` and `event.phase == Ended` for onUp. This even works when your gesture goes off the trackpad and should work for MagicMouse as well. I Will test the MagicMouse later.

You can read a more in-depth analysis of how I came to this conclusion here: http://stylekit.org/blog/2016/02/28/Scroll-wheel/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with these 2 lines of code

```
- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent*)theEvent
{
    BOOL    begin = theEvent.phase & NSEventPhaseBegan;
    BOOL    end   = theEvent.phase & NSEventPhaseEnded || theEvent.momentumPhase & NSEventPhaseEnded;

    if(begin){
       // do something when the scroll begins
       // as store some initial value
    }
    else if(end)
    {
        //... do something when the scroll ends
    }
    else{
       //... do something when scrolling
    }

}
```

Comment: For me theEvent.phase and theEvent.momentumPhase are always always 0 . Any idea why ? 
can this happen because i'm not using Apple mouse ?

Comment: May be. It could depend on the macOS version too. I can tell you that it works with the trackpad on my MacBook Pro with macOS 12.6.1.